# ios 8 Bug UIBarButtonItem with UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose (it snaps to the left)

Tags: ios, ios8, uibarbuttonitem, viewwillappear

I believe there is a bug when using UIBarButtonItem with UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose in iOS8, it only happens with the UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose, when we push to the detailviewcotroller it snaps to the left quickly.

Can someone please confirm if this is a bug and if there is a workaround to fix this problem. I have tested this in a new project.

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(addButton:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn;

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }
```

Comment: This is still a problem, anyone !.

Comment: Related and answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795465/compose-uibarbuttonitem-changes-position-slightly-when-coming-into-view/29905970#29905970

Comment: Correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30027889/1875643

Comment: Thank you guys, this will help, I know its been a while but it still helped because now I can update my App which has been deployed to the app store with the problem back then, but I don't understand why Apple hasn't fixed this yet.