# Compose UIBarButtonItem changes position slightly when coming into view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonsystemitem

When presenting a new view with a UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose button in the navigation bar, the position is slightly off and adjusts after the view has come into view.

[image: Compose button changes position slightly when coming into view]

I think this is a bug in iOS (version 8.3 used). It only happens when using the UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose. It does not happen with other types of Buttons (system, text or custom).

The only code needed to replicate this bug is to use this ViewController code with the view that will come into view:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIBarButtonItem* composeBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera
                                      target:nil
                                      action:nil];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:composeBarButtonItem animated:YES];
}

@end
```

I have created a repository on GitHub with bare minimum code to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/jvdvleuten/iOSComposeBarButtonItemBug

Looks related to this: [UIBarButtonItems shift position when UINavigationController is presented modally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415711/uibarbuttonitems-shift-position-when-uinavigationcontroller-is-presented-modally), except my bug only appears when using the UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose.

Any ideas?

Comment: ya..its a bug when you use compose as a style...but i think you should use `viewDiidAppear` for this code...

Comment: No, when you use the code in viewDidApear, the view comes in view without without the button. That is not standard.

Comment: ya i know...but its a solution for now...instead of that irritating view....thats the better solution...or use sergey Kuryanov answer as a solution

Comment: I am now using an image of the compose button, that works. I will try Sergey's anwser today.

Comment: ok...thats the last option for you to use image of compose....i know it works and works like a charm

Comment: The bug is still here in iOS 9.2...

Comment: Have similar issue using `initWithImage` with a custom X icon image.

Comment: Looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/yGL4iLb.gif    Only happens the first time this view is loaded. For subsequent loads it's in the right position (until app is restarted).  So I don't think it's specific to the compose icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used Sergey's answer, but kept an empty space right of my button. I fixed this with a negative spacer, which now works beautifully:

```
UIBarButtonItem* composeBarButtonItem =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose
                                              target:nil
                                              action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                       target:nil action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = -6;

UIBarButtonItem *dumbBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem new];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[dumbBarButtonItem, negativeSpacer, self.composeBarButtonItem];
```

Comment: Hm.. I used spacer as well, but it didn't work for me. Maybe because I used only spacer and original button. Good catch.

Comment: I also don't know if -6 is the right amount, but it 'feels' right ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a bug in iOS 8.0. This 'jump' occurs before `viewDidAppear`. Here is workaround for this - add another 'dumb'/empty item:

```
UIBarButtonItem* composeBarButtonItem =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose
                                              target:nil
                                              action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *dumbBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem new];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[dumbBarButtonItem, composeBarButtonItem];
```

Comment: I actually keep a empty space right of my compose button and can't get to seem rid of it with an empty view?

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround:

```
let composeButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "UIButtonBarCompose"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "compose:")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = composeButton
```

We can get the image 'UIButtonBarCompose' with [iOS-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor).

Answer (score -1):

I think this is problem of `UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose`. need some correction from apple developer team. Untill apple don't get resolve this bug. you can create your custom button and set it to `rightBarButtonItem` using following code.

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"compose.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 31)];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;

-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Click");
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: May some one down vote my answer. i think you have better answer for same problem. kindly post your answer other then down vote. it may help us in future.

Answer (score -1):

**Nice observation**, This problem solved in `viewDidAppear`. Can you please check this..

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{    
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        UIBarButtonItem* composeBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:nil action:nil];    
        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:composeBarButtonItem animated:YES];    
}
```

This might help you :)

Comment: This will animate my button too late.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is IOS8 bug.

It happens because jumping not a navigation bar item position, its jumping image position inside compose item. This item type seems hasn't override for push animation or something similar, as for example back button.

I think you should create bug on radar and for fix your current trouble, just create custom UIBarButtonItem with the same image.

Comment: I suggest only related thing, and confirm bug by spending my time on investigation. I will not do this next time.

Comment: I have added a bug report with Apple. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -4):

it might happen of animation

try this one. 
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:composeBarButtonItem animated:NO];

hopefully helped :)

Comment: Tried it, has the same result.